# Visual Basic.Net DataGrid Display zero(0) as -

Tags: asp.net, .net, vb.net, datagrid, .net-1.1

In short I have a datagrid.I am retrieving details from Access Database.A number retrieved can be a zero(0).

Is there anyway to display zero(0) as "-" in a datagrid column and at the same time if number is not zero I will format it using "F4"

Comment: datagrid or datagridview ?

Answer (score 0):

You could use a `DataGridView` instead of a `DataGrid` and handle the `CellFormatting` event, see [How to: Customize Data Formatting in the Windows Forms DataGridView Control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z1cc356h.aspx?ppud=4&cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-1) and do something like:

```
If e.Value = 0 Then # ommiting type-/errorchecking for brevity
    e.Value = "-"
End If
```

Comment: Yours answer is that of a DataGridView!

Comment: I no its easier to use DataGridView but am using visual basic.net and there the component which exist is datagrid and not datagridview :(

Comment: @user2530695 Sad. Which features do you need? The `DataGrid` totally sucks :-)